# Angular - Why is my simple function being called many times?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple table in which I use `ngFor` to display the rows.

**app.component.html**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>
                <a>{{myFunc(item?.id) ? "1" : "2"}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`items` is a list which has one object. I would expect `myFunc()` to be evaluated **only once**, for the one object in the `items` list. However, it seems that `myFunc()` is being called **4 times** and I have no idea why.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  items = [{"id": 1}];

  myFunc(itemId) {
    console.log("i was called");
    return true;
  }
}
```

Demo which shows this bug: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j7jgfl. "i was called" is printed to the console 4 times. Can anyone tell me why and what the proper way of calling the function once is?

Comment: Your function (`myFunc`) will be called every time a change detection cycle is ran. If you don't want that to run many times, it is best to do the processing whenever the data that affects the result changes and store that as a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is an expression in my app.component.html called multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401350/why-is-an-expression-in-my-app-component-html-called-multiple-times)

Comment: What @DanielWStrimpel says, or use pipes as they have memoization functionality. Means if the input doesn't change the pipe is aware of it. At ngConf18 there was a brilliant presentation about angular optimization, I think it's available at youtube.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel what do you mean "whenever the data that affects the result changes"? Can you give me an example? In this case, the data that affects the result is item and it changes on every iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Whenever the data being looped over changes, I would run a map over each item and transform it to add an additional property that was the result of this check. This way the only time the operation ever runs is when the data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the console, you can see the following message:

> Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to
>   enable the production mode.

This means, that Angular reruns the change detection in the development mode after each cycle and checks that nothing has changed after the second time. If it does, a warning will be shown because those changes might not be detected in production without the rerun.

If you run `enableProdMode();` in the file `main.ts` before bootstraping (you have to refresh once in Stackblitz), you will see that the function will be called only half as often, two times remain.

The change detection will run for many different reasons when using the default `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. Each time your function will be evaluated. If you want the change detection to run only once, change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush` like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

The change detection is now only run when an `@Input` value changes (the object reference) or an event has been fired.

Answer (score -3):

here is your improved code I don't know I did right or not

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>
                <a>{{myFunc(item) ? "1" : "2"}}</a>
            </td>
        </tr>




myFunc(itemId) {
if(itemId){
console.log("i was called");
    return true;
}else{
return false;
}

  }
```

maybe this will help you